# Properties are not being used - BlackJack Project (always same !false! result but it should be different)

Tags: c#, user-interface, blackjack

I am currently coding a BlackJack Game, and now I am at the Sprint for the HAND and the thing is that the Hand has a HandVALUE and a HandRATING. This Value or Rating represent the Handsproperties or fields. The problem is (you will se it more in the code) that when I create a new HAND in the Console.NetFramework (UI) and type Console.WriteLine(Console.WriteLine("The Value of the hand is: " + hand.HandValue); or Console.WriteLine("The Rating of the hand is: " + hand.HandRating); that they always are 0 and None. 0 = HandValue and None is the HandRating. But they should have other Values and Ratings because (as you will see in the code) there are 3 cards with the value of 7 each = HANDVALUE : 21 and the HandRating should be TripleSeven (because we have 3 7-value cards). 
The Properties should be used and should set the HandValue and HandRating.
(The code is very shortly shown here. If I would left something behind no one would understand the problem and code constructions)

```
Console.WriteLine("HAND - TESTS");
Hand hand = new Hand();
Console.WriteLine("First, output of the cards in the hand at the beginning. If their is nothing to see, the test" +
    "is positive.");
ICard card3 = new Card(CardValue.Seven, CardSuit.Heart);
ICard card4 = new Card(CardValue.Seven, CardSuit.Spade);
ICard card5 = new Card(CardValue.Seven, CardSuit.Diamond);

Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to add one card to the hand:");
Console.ReadLine();
hand.AddCard(card3);
Console.WriteLine("If there is only one card ---> then this hand function is working.");
hand.CardsInHandConsole();

Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to add the next card:");
Console.ReadLine();
hand.AddCard(card4);
hand.AddCard(card5);
Console.WriteLine("If there are 3 cards ---> then this hand function is working.");
hand.CardsInHandConsole();
Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to continue:");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("The Value of the hand is: " + hand.HandValue);
Console.WriteLine("The Rating of the hand is: " + hand.HandRating);
```

The hand class and the last down ENUM HandRating:

```
public class Hand
{
    private List<ICard> _cardsInHand = new List<ICard>();
    private int _handValue;
    private HandRating _handRating;


    public int HandValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _handValue;
        }
        set
        {
            CalculateHandValue();
        }
    }

    public HandRating HandRating
    {
        get
        {
            return _handRating;
        }
        set
        {
            //TripleSeven
            if (_cardsInHand[0].Value == CardValue.Seven &&
                _cardsInHand[1].Value == CardValue.Seven && 
                _cardsInHand[2].Value == CardValue.Seven)
            {
                _handRating = HandRating.TripleSeven;

            }
            //BlackJack
            else if (_cardsInHand[0].Value == CardValue.Jack &&
                     _cardsInHand[1].Value == CardValue.Ace)
            {
                _handRating = HandRating.BlackJack;

            }
            //Busted
            else if (_handValue > 21)
            {
                _handRating = HandRating.Busted;

            }
            //None      
            else { 

                _handRating = HandRating.None;

            }

        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ICard> CardsInHand
    {
        get
        {
            return _cardsInHand;
        }
    }

    public void CardsInHandConsole()
    {
        foreach (ICard card in _cardsInHand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(card.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void AddCard(ICard card)
    {
        _cardsInHand.Add(card);
    }

    public void ClearHand()
    {
        _cardsInHand.Clear();
        _handValue = 0;
        _handRating = HandRating.None;
    }

    private void CalculateHandValue()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= _cardsInHand.Count(); i++)
        {
            ReturnValue(i);
        }
    }

    public void ReturnValue(int index)
    {
        if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Two)
        {
            _handValue =+2;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Three)
        {
            _handValue =+3;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Four)
        {
            _handValue =+4;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Five)
        {
            _handValue =+5;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Six)
        {
            _handValue =+6;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Seven)
        {
            _handValue =+7;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Eight)
        {
            _handValue =+8;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Nine)
        {
            _handValue =+9;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Queen)
        {
            _handValue =+10;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.King)
        {
            _handValue =+10;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Jack)
        {
            _handValue =+10;
        }
        else if (_cardsInHand[index].Value == CardValue.Ace)
        {
            if ((_handValue + 11) > 21)
            {
                _handValue =+1;
            }
            else
            {
                _handValue =+11;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

public enum HandRating
{
  BlackJack,
  TripleSeven,
  Busted,
  None,
}
```

Comment: Indeed code shown does not use setters... Can you please clarify why you believe code shown (which ideally should be cleaned up to be [mcve]) should be calling the setters? Make sure to [edit] post with that information (Side note: setters that ignore value are very suspicious... most likely you actually wanted get-only property that always compute the values)

Comment: Hey :-), so when hand.HandValue is called their should come out the correct HandValue but its always 0. And on HandRating its always None (none is the first parameter in the enum). I am currently not knowing how to construct my code to make the HandValue and HandRating - PROPerties working. I want to put the HandValue and HandRating out on the console in an UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that needed to be changed in order to get the code to work:

In the `Hand` class, `HandValue` and `HandRating` both have setters which does nothing, and should be refactored to be:

```
public int HandValue { get; private set; }
public HandRating HandRating { get; private set; }
```

At the same time, remove the `_handValue` and `_handRating` fields as it's not necessary, and replace with the properties above.

In `CalculateHandValue()`, there's a bug which introduces an `IndexOutOfRange` exception (the <= in the for loop should be <). `CalculateHandValue()` can be refactored to make use of a foreach loop, like below:

```
private void CalculateHandValue()
{
    foreach (var card in _cardsInHand)
    {
        ReturnValue(card);
    }
}
```

`ReturnValue()` doesn't cover all the card values (for instance 7 which was the use case in your console. Also, the incrementing was done incorrectly (should be += 2 instead of = +2). This is what it will look like if we add the new use case and fix the increment:

```
private void ReturnValue(ICard card)
{
    if (card.Value == CardValue.Two)
    {
        HandValue += 2;
    }
    else if (card.Value == CardValue.Three)
    {
        HandValue += 3;
    }
    else if (card.Value == CardValue.Four)
    {
        HandValue += 4;
    }
    else if (card.Value == CardValue.Seven)
    {
        HandValue += 7;
    }
}
```

I'll leave it up to you as an exercise to fill in the rest of the hand values, and maybe look into converting it into a `switch` statement.

Create a new method `CalculateHandRating()` which will use most of the logic from the `HandRating` setter, but with modifications to ensure no no `IndexOutOfRangeException` happens:

```
private void CalculateHandRating()
{
    //TripleSeven
    if (_cardsInHand.Count == 3 &&
        _cardsInHand[0].Value == CardValue.Seven &&
        _cardsInHand[1].Value == CardValue.Seven &&
        _cardsInHand[2].Value == CardValue.Seven)
    {
        HandRating = HandRating.TripleSeven;

    }
    //BlackJack
    else if (_cardsInHand.Count == 2 &&
            _cardsInHand[0].Value == CardValue.Jack &&
                _cardsInHand[1].Value == CardValue.Ace)
    {
        HandRating = HandRating.BlackJack;
    }
    //Busted
    else if (HandValue > 21)
    {
        HandRating = HandRating.Busted;
    }
    //None      
    else
    {
        HandRating = HandRating.None;
    }
}
```

*Note the `_cardsInHand.Count` clauses at each if block to ensure we have the correct number of cards in hand before evaluating.*

Finally, in `AddCard`, add the following like so:

```
public void AddCard(ICard card)
{
    _cardsInHand.Add(card);
    CalculateHandValue();
    CalculateHandRating();
}
```

The class should look like this:

```
public class Hand
{
    private List<ICard> _cardsInHand = new List<ICard>();

    public int HandValue { get; private set; }
    public HandRating HandRating { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<ICard> CardsInHand
    {
        get
        {
            return _cardsInHand;
        }
    }

    public void CardsInHandConsole()
    {
        foreach (ICard card in _cardsInHand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(card.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void AddCard(ICard card)
    {
        _cardsInHand.Add(card);
        CalculateHandValue();
        CalculateHandRating();
    }

    public void ClearHand()
    {
        _cardsInHand.Clear();
        HandValue = 0;
        HandRating = HandRating.None;
    }

    private void CalculateHandValue()
    {
        foreach (var card in _cardsInHand)
        {
            ReturnValue(card);
        }
    }

    private void CalculateHandRating()
    {
        //TripleSeven
        if (_cardsInHand.Count == 3 &&
            _cardsInHand[0].Value == CardValue.Seven &&
            _cardsInHand[1].Value == CardValue.Seven &&
            _cardsInHand[2].Value == CardValue.Seven)
        {
            HandRating = HandRating.TripleSeven;

        }
        //BlackJack
        else if (_cardsInHand.Count == 2 &&
                _cardsInHand[0].Value == CardValue.Jack &&
                    _cardsInHand[1].Value == CardValue.Ace)
        {
            HandRating = HandRating.BlackJack;
        }
        //Busted
        else if (HandValue > 21)
        {
            HandRating = HandRating.Busted;
        }
        //None      
        else
        {
            HandRating = HandRating.None;
        }
    }

    private void ReturnValue(ICard card)
    {
        if (card.Value == CardValue.Two)
        {
            HandValue += 2;
        }
        else if (card.Value == CardValue.Three)
        {
            HandValue += 3;
        }
        else if (card.Value == CardValue.Four)
        {
            HandValue += 4;
        }
        else if (card.Value == CardValue.Seven)
        {
            HandValue += 7;
        }
    }
}
```